# How to check if characters in a string are capitalized or not in increments of two - Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Im trying to create a function that puts "op" in-between each character of a string. However if o or p is next to a letter that is capitalized, o and/or p must be capitalized. For example:

Given input: 'aB'

Should output: 'aoPB'

I have tried going through a for loop for each character in the string 
and checking the character using `.islower()` and `.isupper()`

```
def oPify(s):

    s2 = ''

    for i in range(0,len(s),1) :


        if i == len(s)-1 :
            s2 = s2 + s[i]

            return s2
        elif s[i].islower()==True and s[i+1].islower==True:

            s2 = s2 + s[i]+'op'
        elif s[i].islower()==True and s[i+1].isupper()==True;

            s2 = s2 + s[i]+'oP'
        elif s[i].isupper()==True and s[i+1].islower==True:

            s2 = s2 + s[i]+'Op'
        elif s[i].isupper()==True and s[i+1].isupper==True:

            s2 = s2 + s[i]+'OP'
```

I expected if I put `s` as 'ab' to get 'aopb' however I only get 'b'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't actually calling the `islower`/`isupper` methods when you don't use the parentheses at the end. You're just referencing the object associated with the method.

Add the parentheses & your function should now work:

```
def oPify(s):

    s2 = ''

    for i in range(0,len(s),1) :

        if i == len(s)-1 :
            s2 = s2 + s[i]

            return s2
        elif s[i].islower()==True and s[i+1].islower()==True:

            s2 = s2 + s[i]+'op'
        elif s[i].islower()==True and s[i+1].isupper()==True:

            s2 = s2 + s[i]+'oP'
        elif s[i].isupper()==True and s[i+1].islower()==True:

            s2 = s2 + s[i]+'Op'
        elif s[i].isupper()==True and s[i+1].isupper()==True:

            s2 = s2 + s[i]+'OP'
```

(This code also fixes the semi-colon typo.)